# xargs - multiple commands and rm at the end

Tags: shell, find, xargs

I'm trying to remove the file that I was working on previously but it's not letting me, please help. Here is the command I run:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -print0 |
  xargs -0i ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "{}.mp3" |
  rm -rf {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel installed you can do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k {.}.mp3 '&&' rm {}
```

It will run one ffmpeg process per CPU core.

To learn more watch the intro videos: http://pi.dk/1

Comment: Hi, I think I might have to try this. I have a 3.2GHz Quad Core Xeon E3-1230 CPU, Passmark CPU mark Score of 8,200, 32GB ram - and I can't do more than 4 ffmpeg commands without being overloaded... not sure why... i might have to consider this if you're telling me that I can get each ffmpeg session to run on it's own cpu core.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'overloaded'. GNU Parallel will most likely detect 8 cores (because of hyperthreading) and start 8 ffmpeg jobs in parallel. GNU Parallel does not guarantee a process will run on its own core. It simply start the number of jobs corresponding to the number of cores. Your O/S takes care of the rest.

Comment: I tweaked it up and ran it like this and it worked great!: 

find . -type f -name '*' | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -sameq {.}.mp4 '&&' rm {}

Comment: So if I understood this coorectly. does this mean that I can do a | and run another command i want with parallel? For example, if I want to upload the recently encoded file to an ftp server, how would i do this with a single line?

Comment: Something like (where `upload` is the program you use to upload with): `find . -type f -name '*.flac' | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -sameq {.}.mp4 '&&' upload {.}.mp4 '&&' rm {}`

Comment: Thanks Ole - I'm starting to get attached to this parallel thing if I can go about adding as many '&&' as I want to run a continuation of tasks

Comment: Use '&&' if you need the previous command to succeed. Use ';' if you do not care if the previous command fails.

Comment: On macOS, run `brew install parallel` and off you go! thank you very much, this worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You are piping the output of the `ffmpeg` call(s) into the `rm` command. Since `ffmpeg` produces no interesting output and `rm` does not read any input, this doesn't do anything.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I think you want to remove the flac file after processing. You have several choices: you can first convert all the ffmpeg files, then remove them all; or you can remove each file after it's been processed. I advise the latter, otherwise it will be difficult to only remove the flac file if the conversion succeeded.

Rather than use `xargs`, it's simpler to use `find … -exec` here. For each flac file, call `ffmpeg`, and then delete the file if ffmpeg succeeded. If your find doesn't have the `-delete` action, use `-exec rm {} \;` instead. Use an intermediate shell to construct the output file name.

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' \
     -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "${0%.*}.mp3"' {} \; \
     -delete
```

You can use the `rm` command inside the shell snippet instead.

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' \
     -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "${0%.*}.mp3" && rm "$0"' {} \;
```

With some versions of `find`, if you want the output file to be called `foo.flac.mp3`, you can skip the intermediate shell.

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' \
     -exec ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k {}.mp3 \; \
     -delete
```

Comment: The second option looks like the best AND the simplest option, doing exactly what the question requires, using no pipes. Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The command `rm` doesn't take input from standard input, so you need to send it input using `xargs` just like you did for `ffmpeg`

try this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -print0 |
    xargs -0i bash -c 'ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k \"{}.mp3" ; rm -rf {}'
```

This adds `rm` into the command `xargs` executes, essentially creating an inline shell script using `bash -c`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "it's not letting me" is not the best way to describe the problem. You should post the error message or describe what happens.

Second, I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve, but you're not using `rm` with `xargs`, you just pipe something to `rm`. That's not how `rm` works.

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -print0 | xargs -0i rm "{}"
```

would probably work, for example. I'm not using `rm -r` here, because `find` only looks for files anyway.